# Rails Image Assets Not Loading

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, nginx, asset-pipeline, digital-ocean

I've been dealing with the complications of the rails asset pipeline in production for about a week now. I'm finally almost done. I have two images that I'm referencing in a css file.

The css file is being precompiled and the precompiled images are referenced accordingly in the file.

```
background:url(/assets/k-opacity-70-f75f0169dbfb178b3aedbf11429dfd68.png);

#intro{background:#111 url(/assets/intro-bg-12afabffede338ee9a72dbff2488bfea.jpg) no-repeat center;
```

I have edited my config/application.rb according to the suggestion on the Rails website to ensure I'm precompiling all the files I need.

```
 config.assets.precompile << Proc.new do |path|
  if path =~ /\.(css|js)\z/
    full_path = Rails.application.assets.resolve(path).to_path
    app_assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_path
    if full_path.starts_with? app_assets_path
      puts "including asset: " + full_path
      true
    else
      puts "excluding asset: " + full_path
      false
    end
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Is there something I need to do besides making sure the assets are precompiled?
My app is being deployed to a digital ocean server with nginx and passenger.

Comment: Make sure nginx is serving your assets. http://dennisreimann.de/blog/configuring-nginx-for-the-asset-pipeline/ It is not however very clear what you specifically asking, what problem are you encountering?

Comment: The images on my website aren't loading. Particularly the ones I listed in the css. So, I'm trying to figure out why they won't appear. I can view them for instance http://162.243.242.52/assets/intro-bg-12afabffede338ee9a72dbff2488bfea.jpg  but they do not appear on my web page. I've seen that link before. I've set up the nginx.conf and my production.rb already, so I'm not sure what else I need to do.

Comment: I think the problem is with your css. Using the developer tool in Chrome the images are clearly being loaded. But there is something wrong in the css, preventing them from being seen. Maybe a div with height: 0 or something.

Comment: #intro {
   background: #111 url("<%= asset_path 'intro-bg.jpg' %>")  no-repeat center;
   overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: header {
   height: 54px;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 99999;
   background: url("<%= asset_path 'k-opacity-70.png' %>");
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;

}

Comment: Do you think it's one of those?

Comment: I would guess so yes, but I'm not a CSS expert by any means. Maybe you could try creating a new question with this specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here:

```
background: url("<%= asset_path 'k-opacity-70.png' %>"); position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }
```

---

**Helper**

There is a helper called [`asset_url`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html) which is highly recommended for CSS. I would do this:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss #-> notice the extension
background: asset_url("k-opacity-70.png");
```

This will make sure that your assets are referenced correctly, especially when you send them to your server. This may sound simplistic, but we've had issues in Heroku (I know you use DO) before, whereby the files didn't render, as their fingerprints were incorrect

May get downvoted for this (as it's basically the same as your code), but it's what works for us

---

**Fingerprinting**

Secondly, I would ensure your fingerprinted images are actually present in your `public/assets` folder

The precompliation process generally creates a series of `images`, `stylesheets` & `js` files which have to be referenced in your assets. This is handled with the helpers like the one I referenced above, but it also means they can be mis-referenced

--

If you have the correct files in your folders, the problem will be how you're referencing them, else it will be a problem with the precompilation process itself (which is in the remit of `application.css`)

Comment: How would you call the asset_url or asset-url method from javascript?

Comment: for rails 6, I used `asset-url` instead of `asset_url` from the answer (notice `-` instead of `_`). This blog post helped me to fix the error [Assets, Webpacker and Rails 6. Why your images and css aren’t showing up. -Heroku vs Development](https://medium.com/@yoanante/assets-webpacker-and-rails-6-why-your-images-and-css-arent-showing-up-heroku-vs-development-de85047148de)